# Spring mvc / Tomcat Servlet Container: multi threading initialization (and who spawns them?)

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-container

I have tried to look online, and found only few places that says spring is actually multi-threaded. Even those, seems to *hint* it simply uses a multi-threaded servlet container (as far as I understood, the single-threaded servlet containers are mostly deprecated, hence they all are multi-threaded these days).

I was hoping someone could clarify and validate that information; is the multi threading truly comes from servlet container and not spring?

And the more important question is, how do I initialize a per-thread data? As part of my database connection managing, I am using a library which requires me to initialize data in each thread.

Currently, I am checking a value on every call to that library, to know to initialize it.
But I prefer to simply initialize it every time a thread starts.

I believe it should be possible; After all, someone is creating those threads that keep calling my spring controllers.

p.s.
I am using the default servlet container in spring, which is Tomcat. I also tried doing a quick search for per-thread initialization and multi-threading in tomcat, but couldn't find any clear information on when a new thread actually spawn, or some information about a thread pool being used. I could be wrong though, and the multi threading is

Comment: Yes, the Servlet container manages a thread pool which. When it receives a request, it dispatches a thread to handle it.

Comment: Can you tell me then how can I call a function of my own, every time a new thread is spawned?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to solve the wrong problem. There's a multitude of database connection pool managers out there, not the least of which is the one that is packaged in your standard Tomcat distribution. Are you aware of [javax.sql.DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html)?